# arch linux (linux-5.14.16) "Dependency failed for /boot/efi"

Tags: boot, arch-linux

Recently did a `pacman -Syyuu` to update my Arch Linux system like i usually do.
The next time i booted it gave this error:

```
[ TIME ] Timed out waiting for device /dev/disk/by-uuid/4C01-B401.
[DEPEND] Dependency failed for /boot/efi.
[DEPEND] Dependency failed for Local File Systems.
[DEPEND] Dependency failed for File System Check on /dev/disk/by-uuid/4C01-B40.
You are in emergency mode. After logging in, type "journalctl -xb" to view
system logs, "systemctl reboot" to reboot, "systemctl default" or "exit"
to boot into default mode.
```

blkid:

```
/dev/sdb: UUID="4335-E2C7" BLOCK_SIZE="512" TYPE="vfat"
/dev/sda2: UUID="a3694f4e-2353-40f1-9859-dabf5aa96add" TYPE="swap" PARTUUID="321a2961-c3b1-7d49-91ea-0f1ba6470491"
/dev/sda3: UUID="a53bdf0b-6360-42ab-9cfb-fa7287d1e217" BLOCK_SIZE="4096" TYPE="ext4" PARTUUID="30089536-c588-db4e-b6cd-4f47aec972b9"
/dev/sda1: LABEL_FATBOOT="BOOT" LABEL="BOOT" BLOCK_SIZE="512" TYPE="vfat" PARTUUID="ac788985-14d7-6742-89a0-17af02f977be"
```

dmesg: https://pastebin.com/Pphi1P6N
journal: https://pastebin.com/mKFbcNxq
pacman.log: https://pastebin.com/iEEfTxnZ

I tried to follow instructions from https://bbs.archlinux.org/viewtopic.php?id=152284 and https://bbs.archlinux.org/viewtopic.php?id=177678 but i still get the same error during boot.

thanks in advance.